# Find fastest sort for given range of numbers

Tags: runtime-analysis, sorting, radix-sort

I encountered a question from a test that I cant understand the answer

> given a range of numbers $[0...(logn)^{logn}-1]$ we need to find the quickest sort available and give his running time

now it seems like something to do with radix sort but if I try to switch bases to $logn$ I get $n$ numbers that each contain $logn\cdot log_{logn}(logn)=log(n)$ numbers. aradix sort in this situation will cost $n\cdot log(n)$ not good enough. if we switch to base n we will get something strange - $$log(n)\cdot log_n(logn)$$ I know that this is smaller number of digits but I have no idea if it will work with radix sort

any Idias?

Comment: Could you clarify how many numbers we are sorting? Is it $n$?

Comment: yes sorting $n$ numbers, by the way the answer is $nloglogn$ I cant figure out why...

Comment: any help?? somebody?